# How to arrive at this sufficient condition for convergence of Taylor Series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

So I have been studying the convergence of Taylor series from [Tom M Apostol](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471000051). There is a theorem which states the sufficient condition for convergence of Taylor series. Quoting the theorem we've

> Assume $f$ is infinitely differentiable in an open interval $I = (a -
>  r, a + r)$, and assume that there is a positive constant $A$  such
>    that  $$ |f^{(n)}(x)| \le A^n$$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$ and every $x$
>    in $I$. Then the Taylor's series generated by $f$ at $a$ converges to
>   $f(x)$ for each $x$ in $I$.

My question is how to arrive at $|f^{(n)}(x)| \le A^n$ deductively ? I tried looking it up on the internet but haven't found anything that solves my issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean how to deduce that such a bound would be a sufficient condition for convergence? It is a strange question asking how to deduce a hypothesis. Hypotheses are starting points. One could guess, or motivate a hypothesis. In the case of necessary and sufficient conditions one could deduce it, but this one is only a sufficient condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion
$$
|f^n(x)| \le A^n
$$
is a *hypothesis* in this theorem. You can't "arrive at it deductively" in general. When it happens to be true for any particular function $f$ then you can conclude something about the Taylor series for that function.

For example, the $n$th derivatives of $\sin$ are $\sin$ and $\cos$. Their absolute values are always at most $1$. This theorem then implies that the Taylor series for $\sin$ converges everywhere to the value of the function.